# how to align label and span properly

Tags: html, css

I put together this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrzey328/14/)

What I have is 2 divs and then one of them has 2 more divs in it. What I am trying to do it properly position label and span within second div

```
  <div id="someotherdiv">

  </div>
  <div class="reportuserinfo">
        <div class="leftdivinfo">
             <label>Teacher:</label><span>Teacher Name</span><br/>
            <label>District:</label><span>District Name</span><br/>
            <label>School:</label><span>School Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="rightdivinfo">
            <label>Class:</label><span>Class Name</span><br/>
            <label>Content:</label><span id="currcontent">Content</span><br/>
            <label>Unit:</label><span id="currunit"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you look in fiddle right now label is floating to the right and so is span but they look strange, what I am attempting to accomplish is something like this on both sides of second div:

```
 Teacher:   Teacher Name
District:   District Name
  School:   School Name
```

The way they look right now is

```
Teacher:     Teacher Name
District:   District Name
School:    School Name
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm assuming this issue is for responsiveness design? On my screen the text is displaying the way you want it, on one line. When I reduce the screen size then I see the issue you're having. I would say move the pink block below the yellow block and increase the width of .leftdivinfo

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean.. here i tried to change my code a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrzey328/21/)
however, they are in opposite direction... label in this format should be on the left and span on the right

Comment: Any luck with the solution? Please accept any of the answers if they helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added width:30%; in your css class ".reportuserinfo label" and it fixed the issue ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6z77xwk/)). You need to define width in order to fix the text alignment issue. You can adjust space margins as per your requirements.

Here is how your code looks like to me now :-

```
.reportuserinfo label {
    float: left;;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a min-width style in your css apart from width:40% to ensure that the text you are trying to write does not scroll if browser width is decreased

```
.leftdivinfo {
    float:left;
    min-width: 200px;
    width:40%;
    background: yellow;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: ok... I added that but I still need it to be in the right position :)
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrzey328/23/)

Comment: by right position I assume that you want all your colons aligned? If yes, have a min-width defined for a class you apply on the label. If you want to have your left and right divs in a single line, have a min-width defined for reportuserinfo class as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using tables? You could enclose this information in a table, then right-align the text in the left column:

```css
table {
  border: none;
}

td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Class Teacher:</td>
    <td>John Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>District:</td>
    <td>Smithsville</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>School:</td>
    <td>Smith's High School</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry it has to be divs

Comment: @coder what is it about the divs that you need in particular? This solution is by far the most elegant one, I could help you find a workaround to make it work properly if there is something that is limiting you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `width` to `auto` and adding `display:inline-block`.

```
.leftdivinfo {
  float:left;
  width: auto;
  background: yellow;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display:inline-block
}
```

Tables might be a better way to make this.

**EDIT:**
I see you want the colons aligned, add `min-width:70px;` to the label class.